# Print Pagination length and pagination numbers

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
pagination = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^='MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_']")
            print(len(pagination)) #5
```

```
I'm getting css Selector from below code

<div class="col-md-12">
        
        <ul class="pagination">
            
            <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_liPrev" class="disabled">
                <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_PreviousPageButton" title="«" class="aspNetDisabled">«</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                
            </li>

            
                    <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_0" class="active">
                        <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_0" class="aspNetDisabled">1 </a>
                    </li>
                
                    <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_1">
                        <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_1" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$Repeater1$ctl01$PageLink&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">2 </a>
                    </li>
                
                    <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_2">
                        <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_2" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$Repeater1$ctl02$PageLink&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">3 </a>
                    </li>
                
                    <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_3">
                        <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_3" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$Repeater1$ctl03$PageLink&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">4 </a>
                    </li>
                
                    <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_4">
                        <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_4" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$Repeater1$ctl04$PageLink&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">5 </a>
                    </li>
                
    
            <li>
                <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_NextSectionButton" title="..." href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$NextSectionButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">...</a>
            </li>
            <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_liNext">
                <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_NextPageButton" title="»" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$NextPageButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">»</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ908.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjU7J.png)

1. I have total 9 pages,however i am getting page length 5
2. How can i get all the length(9)
3. Based on this length i am going to 5th page, after that i am not able go th 6th because i'm getting only length 5.
4. Is there a way to go one after another till 9th page and go back to any URl, after reaching 9th page
5. Thanks in advance

Comment: You do it like a human does it.  If there is a Pager_NextSectionButton (the "..." part), then you have to click it to move on to the next set of pages.

Comment: i am running automation python script, it is not selecting

Comment: Then what's the question?  If there is a "..." node, you cannot possibly know how many pages there are until you click that to page through to the end.  After that, you can go fetch your original page again, if you need to.

Comment: yes i want like thaat

Answer (score 0):

So you'd do something like this to keep clicking the next button. Not sure if the next button gets disabled.

```
while True:
   try:
       WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_NextPageButton"))).click()
   except:
       break
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```